# How to configure Nginx with CloudFront to benefit from CloudFront's caching?

Tags: caching, nginx, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control

I have a website with Wordpress. This website is hosted on Nginx & php-fpm. I added CloudFront to increase performance and decrease origin server load.

However, I can see in Chrome's developer tools console that all resources has `Miss from CloudFront` value in `x-cache` header.

I'm not sure how I should configure Nginx & CloudFront to work properly and benefit from caching.

I believe it's all about proper headers that should be set by Nginx (eg. `Cache-Control: public` for images?). I can't find any examples that would cover all cases and wouldn't mess up Wordpress Admin Panel (this one shouldn't be cached, right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix could be to install the [WP Super Cache plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/);  has CDN support besides other things.

In the Nginx side you could do something like this for static content:

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

You can add as many directives, not necesary only images, for example:

```
location ~* \.(?:cur|gz|svg|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
     access_log off;
     add_header Cache-Control "max-age=2592000";
     #... more options
}
```

The `?:` prefix is a 'non-capturing' mark, meaning we don't require the pattern to be captured into `$1` which should help improve performance.

You can find more info about the [Nginx expires option here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires).

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. However, I have a feeling that your answer could be improved a bit. I mean, `ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png` aren't the only ones I should be caching, right? (Or are?)

Comment: right, and that's basically what the WP plugging will do by generating static content of your pages.

Comment: I added the lines that you provided but although the resources have new headers, they still have `Miss from CloudFront`. Does it need more time to apply?

Comment: @Defozo the first time you request a specific resource from a specific CloudFront edge, it's always going to be a Miss. There should be no need to wait.  What you have configured for forwarding (headers, cookies, query strings) will also determine how often a request is a Hit, and correct configuration of the Cache Behavior TTLs or "use origin cache headers" also has an impact.